# Electrical Roughing-ins

Tags: optimization, circuitry

[image]

The 27 junction boxes at the ends of electrical conduits must all have a green and red wire taps for the lighting fixtures. Only one wire fits the conduits for safety. The wires should be connected on the power source terminals at the ground floor level. But there are no extra conduits available for the electrician to do that so he decided to remove and utilize 2 of the installed conduits. How would he wire up the ceilings?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's being asked. Is it this? "Remove two of the 54 edges of the cube in order to make connections to the two terminals of the solar battery, going to the obvious two junction boxes on the ground floor, and then find a way of placing red and green wire along some of the edges so that (1) no edge has two wires, (2) all the red wires are connected, (3) all the green wires are connected, (4) there's both red and green wire at every cube-vertex, (5) red goes to the RH battery terminal, and (6) green goes to the LH battery terminal."

Comment: yes.I'm sure that is the correct understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding the problem statement (see my comment above) then I think this does it:

> [image]

Comment: Why would we remove two edges if we can just put any wire there?

Comment: Because we need those two conduits to connect to the battery.